# how to change gradient position on mouse movement?

Tags: html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to build more User Interaction on a website. As my website has a gradient, I was inspired on how the gradient moves along with the mouse hovering on thing site http://www.impossible-bureau.com/.

If any one could help me with a code to do the same background effect would be great!

Comment: its a combination of javascript plus css, they are moving the css classes between div's, its simple you should give it a try first and then ask if ur stuck

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a do-it-for-me request, not a question.

Answer (score 0):

See this quick Fiddle for an example, no JS involved (you will have to work a lot to have something as smooth and good looking as they have, but I don't see any movement in the background :) only the foreground has different states) :

```css
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/49/Zdiar1.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
}

div
{
    background-color: darkblue;
    height: 100%;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    padding: 1rem;
    transition: .5s ease;
}

div:nth-of-type(4)
{
    background-color: darkblue;
}

div:hover
{
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium ipsa vitae quidem quod soluta vel impedit eligendi eius minus quis optio recusandae numquam iure laborum voluptatum facilis cum similique excepturi.</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium ipsa vitae quidem quod soluta vel impedit eligendi eius minus quis optio recusandae numquam iure laborum voluptatum facilis cum similique excepturi.</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium ipsa vitae quidem quod soluta vel impedit eligendi eius minus quis optio recusandae numquam iure laborum voluptatum facilis cum similique excepturi.</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium ipsa vitae quidem quod soluta vel impedit eligendi eius minus quis optio recusandae numquam iure laborum voluptatum facilis cum similique excepturi.</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs @sodawillow but my question was in regards to the gradient degree. Just to clarify I was looking for something  like this http://codepen.io/andreasstorm/pen/syvoL. The same effect  for the background of the website but on the mouse cursor movement.